# A strange compiling error happen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

A strange compling problem as below:

[image]

I have imported the Class "ViewController" correctly , Why I receive the error compiling message as shown in the pic? how to fix it? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this instead of the import:

```
@class ViewController
```

Are you importing PGConductor in ViewControll.h also?
Might be a cycling behaivour with your imports.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `@class ViewController` after `#import "ViewController.h"`

Hope your problem will be resolved